# Copy input value to another input after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

All I'm trying to do is to replicate what I write on a label to be copied to another label, but nothing happens. I want what I type on main input to be copied to label1 input. Thanks in advance

```
<head>
<body>
<title>form</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='form' width='100%' height='100%'>


    <input id='mainId' type="text" name="main" value="" width="100px">main</input>
    <br>
  <input  id='1' type="text" name="label1" value=""  width="20px">label1</input>

</div>

<button>Click</button>
  </body>
  <script>
          var change;
            setTimeout(function() {

              change = document.getElementById('mainId').value;

            }, 1);


               $("button").click(function(){
               $("#1").attr("value", change);
             });

  </script>
</head>
```

[image]

Comment: your title says you want it on page load, on question description you say when you type, which one?

Comment: Also, `input` tag is self closing, it cannot contains text or other elements inside it like you did: `...>main</input>`

Comment: Other problem is, your `<title>` tag is inside body and there is a `</head>` down the code. You have many semantic errors on your code, fix then first, bbefore trying to fix JS problems. Use a HTML validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by fixing the HTML, that is really problematic in your code.

1. tags like, `<script>`, `<title>` and some others should be inside `<head>`, not body.
2. Your `<head>` should come before `<body>`.
3. `<input>` is a self-closing tag, it can not contain text or other elements, it should be: `.../>main` and not `...>main</input>`

Said that, we can now go to Javascript problems:

1. You don't need a global variable `change` neither a timer.
2. All you need is a click listener, as you already have.
3. Inside the listener get the [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) from your first input (`#mainId`) and set it as `value` of your second input (`#1`).

See below code.

My tips for you: **Read documentations**, to learn more abount semantic of HTML and the methods from JS and jQuery.

Use a **HTML validator**, like [this one](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  let changedTxt = $("#mainId").val()
  $("#1").val(changedTxt)
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='form' width='100%' height='100%'>
    <input id='mainId' type="text" name="main" value="" width="100px" />main
    <br>
    <input id='1' type="text" name="label1" value="" width="20px" />label1
  </div>

  <button>Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!